# Linux boot - stop the kernel switching to a new framebuffer mode clearing output

Tags: boot, ubuntu-12.04, resolution, linux-kernel, framebuffer

I'm working on an embedded system (based on`Ubuntu 12.04 LTS`) and I'm customizing its kernel. I'm having some problem with `upstart`, `mountall` and `plymouth`. Nothing unsolvable I suppose, but the real problem is that I can't diagnose properly what's going on because the kernel (or maybe `plymouth`) changes the video mode in the middle of the boot process. This completely wipes entire lines of log and prevents any debugging of kernel misconfigurations.

My `Grub2` config seems to be ok with:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=force noplymouth"

GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768x32
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

Here is some relevant output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GSE Express Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GSE Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
```

And here is the relevant portion of my kernel configuration:

```
CONFIG_AGP=y
CONFIG_AGP_INTEL=y
CONFIG_VGA_ARB=y
CONFIG_VGA_ARB_MAX_GPUS=16
CONFIG_DRM=y
CONFIG_DRM_KMS_HELPER=y
CONFIG_DRM_I915=y
CONFIG_DRM_I915_KMS=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_OUTPUT_CONTROL=y
CONFIG_FB=y
CONFIG_FB_BOOT_VESA_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_FB_CFB_FILLRECT=y
CONFIG_FB_CFB_COPYAREA=y
CONFIG_FB_CFB_IMAGEBLIT=y
CONFIG_FB_MODE_HELPERS=y
CONFIG_FB_VESA=y
CONFIG_BACKLIGHT_LCD_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_BACKLIGHT_CLASS_DEVICE=y
CONFIG_VGA_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_VGACON_SOFT_SCROLLBACK=y
CONFIG_VGACON_SOFT_SCROLLBACK_SIZE=640
CONFIG_DUMMY_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE_DETECT_PRIMARY=y
CONFIG_FONT_8x8=y
CONFIG_FONT_8x16=y
CONFIG_LOGO=y
CONFIG_LOGO_LINUX_MONO=y
CONFIG_LOGO_LINUX_VGA16=y
CONFIG_LOGO_LINUX_CLUT224=y
```

Every other custom/stock kernel boot fine with that `Grub2` config. What I would like to have is a single flow of messages on a single console (retaining one screen resolution) from the bootup logo till the login prompt. Does anybody know what I have to tweak to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that finally I've reached a reasonable `framebuffer` configuration. These are the relevant settings inside my kernel `.config`:

```
CONFIG_AGP=y
CONFIG_AGP_INTEL=y
CONFIG_VGA_ARB=y
CONFIG_VGA_ARB_MAX_GPUS=16
CONFIG_VIDEO_OUTPUT_CONTROL=y
CONFIG_FB=y
CONFIG_FIRMWARE_EDID=y
CONFIG_FB_BOOT_VESA_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_FB_CFB_FILLRECT=y
CONFIG_FB_CFB_COPYAREA=y
CONFIG_FB_CFB_IMAGEBLIT=y
CONFIG_FB_VESA=y
CONFIG_VGA_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_VGACON_SOFT_SCROLLBACK=y
CONFIG_VGACON_SOFT_SCROLLBACK_SIZE=640
CONFIG_DUMMY_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE_DETECT_PRIMARY=y
CONFIG_FONT_8x8=y
CONFIG_FONT_8x16=y
CONFIG_LOGO=y
CONFIG_LOGO_LINUX_MONO=y
CONFIG_LOGO_LINUX_VGA16=y
CONFIG_LOGO_LINUX_CLUT224=y
```

and this is the `diff` between the old and the new `framebuffer` configuration:

```
#> diff oldcfg.txt newcfg.txt
--- oldcfg.txt  2012-10-01 17:30:01.000000000 +0200
+++ newcfg.txt  2012-10-01 17:29:43.000000000 +0200
@@ -2,20 +2,14 @@
 CONFIG_AGP_INTEL=y
 CONFIG_VGA_ARB=y
 CONFIG_VGA_ARB_MAX_GPUS=16
-CONFIG_DRM=y
-CONFIG_DRM_KMS_HELPER=y
-CONFIG_DRM_I915=y
-CONFIG_DRM_I915_KMS=y
 CONFIG_VIDEO_OUTPUT_CONTROL=y
 CONFIG_FB=y
+CONFIG_FIRMWARE_EDID=y
 CONFIG_FB_BOOT_VESA_SUPPORT=y
 CONFIG_FB_CFB_FILLRECT=y
 CONFIG_FB_CFB_COPYAREA=y
 CONFIG_FB_CFB_IMAGEBLIT=y
-CONFIG_FB_MODE_HELPERS=y
 CONFIG_FB_VESA=y
-CONFIG_BACKLIGHT_LCD_SUPPORT=y
-CONFIG_BACKLIGHT_CLASS_DEVICE=y
 CONFIG_VGA_CONSOLE=y
 CONFIG_VGACON_SOFT_SCROLLBACK=y
 CONFIG_VGACON_SOFT_SCROLLBACK_SIZE=640
```

This configuration produces a `Knoppix`-like boot output. I still don't understand who or what clears the screen just before the login prompt appears, but I'm quite satisfied for now. I'll update this answer if I'll be able to pinpoint the culprit.

### EDIT: found the (two) culpright(s).

After hours of googling, I found the solution in [this thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/fedora-35/how-to-inhibit-the-clear-screen-before-login-prompt-825386/) and [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92054/log-boot-messages-on-tty1-instead-of-tty7). This procedure works for `Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS` as also described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/195926/63606), but it should not differ too much for other distributions.

First, add **`console=tty1`** to your `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` (I also suggest to add **`noplymouth`** to inhibit `plymouth` and its useless splashscreen).

```
#> sudo vi /etc/default/grub

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty1 noplymouth"
```

This forces the kernel log to be printed on `tty1` instead of `tty7` and avoid the `tty` switch before the login prompt.

Then just go into `/etc/init` and edit one or more of `tty1.conf`, `tty2.conf`, `tty3.conf`, `tty4.conf`, `tty5.conf`, `tty6.conf` or `console.conf`. I edited them all adding **`--noclear`** option to the `getty` command. For example, editing `tty1.conf`:

```
#> sudo vi /etc/init/tty1.conf
```

you'll have to replace:

```
respawn
exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
```

with:

```
respawn
exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 --noclear tty1
```

That's all, now your system should boot in a single `tty` without clearing it.

Answer (score 0):

Detach virtual console early on during the boot up process.

echo 0 > /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon$console_index/bind

$console_index -> 0,1,2

echo 0 > /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon0/bind
for /dev/tty0

echo 0 > /sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon1/bind
for /dev/tty1